# How should I build this Django model to do what I want

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, one-to-one

This is what I had before (but realized that you can't obviously do it in this order:

```
class MasterAdmin(models.Model):
    """
    A permanent admin (one per Account) that shouldn't be deleted.
    """
    admin = models.OneToOneField(AccountAdmin)

class Account(models.Model):
    """
    A top-level account in the system.
    """
    masteradmin = models.OneToOneField(MasterAdmin)


class AccountAdmin(models.Model):
    """
    An Account admin that can be deleted.  This includes limited permissions.
    """
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
```

I think you can see what I want to do from the example. I want to have an MasterAccountAdmin which shares the attributes from AccountAdmin. The purpose is that I want to give people the ability to delete an AccountAdmin, but not MasterAccountAdmin. I didn't want to just have an attribute on AccountAdmin called "master = models.BooleanField()".

Obviously this example won't work because MasterAdmin is referencing AccountAdmin before its creation, but I wanted to show what I'm trying to achieve. Am I thinking of this all wrong?

Comment: -1: Really poor question title.  Can you please fix the title to be your real question?  Perhaps "How do I define three models with circular references" or something that describes the problem.

Comment: It's a decent title if you read the question before focusing on the code only. I'm not asking how to technically achieve what my code states. I'm asking what is a good way to write a model (versus my way) to achieve the high-level goal which I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just make is_master a property of AccountAdmin and then override the delete() method to ensure is_master is not true?

Comment: This is a better approach than what the OP is doing, but I wanted to answer his question related to forward references.

Comment: Oh, good point. I was so busy with the architecture I didn't see the question (and that was an issue I ran into when first working in Django too).

Answer (score 2):

When you have forward references, use the quotes.

```
admin = models.OneToOneField('AccountAdmin')
```

[See the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself...

Comment: Thanks! BTW, is this very Pythonic to do (this in quotes thing)?

Comment: It's a special feature of django, to accommodate this kind of relationship.  It's perfectly acceptable practice, but it isn't supported by python explicitly.

Comment: What jcd said. I updated my answer to have a link to the docs.